# Change values between two specefic values in Numpy array

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, numpy-ndarray

In a binary numpy array, I want to select ones, and convert all zeros between to 1.

for example:

```
np.array([0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1])
```

should be converted to:

```
np.array([0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1])
```

or if I have the follwing arrays:

```
np.array([0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0])
np.array([0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0])
```

they should remain unchanged.
Is there a fast way to implement it?

Comment: Thanks! All the answers there failed to do the job.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My approach:

```
start, end = a.argmax(), a[::-1].argmax() + 1

# only update if there is at least a one:
if a[start]==1:
    a[start:-end] = 1
```